# Django REST Framework viewset doesn't obey pagination_class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've successfully implemented a custom `pagination_class` for a certain `ModelViewSet` in my app, but I'm having issues implemeting a separate custom pagination_class for a basic `ViewSet`.

Here's the working pagination_class and related ModelViewSet:

```
class Model1Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
  page_size = 10
  page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
  max_page_size = 100

class Model1ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
API endpoint that returns the instances of Model1
"""

  queryset = Model1.objects.all()
  serializer_class = Model1Serializer
  pagination_class = Model1Pagination

  @list_route()
  def extra(self, request)
    ....
    return <something>
```

And this is the pagination_class and ViewSet which isn't working:

```
class Model2Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
  page_size = 1
  page_query_param = 'page_size'
  max_page_size = 1

class Model2GenericViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
"""
API endpoint to return the instances of Model2
"""

  def get_queryset():
    return Model2.objects.all()
  pagination_class = Model2Pagination

  def list(self, request):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = Model2Serializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I suppose I could alter the `Model2GenericViewSet` to function as a `ModelViewSet`, but I was hoping to avoid the refactor, and the DRF docs mention:

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets

So I figured using a `ViewSet` would be alright. I didn't originally specify a `get_queryset()` on the ViewSet, and my initial thought was that I needed to do so, however adding that didn't affect behavior.

After some testing with the `Model1Pagination`, I'm not seeing pagination apply to the results of the `extra()` method in the `Model1` viewset- it's not a method I need pagination for, so I only just found this out.

Does the doc quote above mean that pagination literally only applies to built-in viewset methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ViewSet class inherits from APIView. The relation is:
View(in Django) -> APIView -> ViewSet

The ModelViewSetclass inherits from GenericViewSet . The relation is:
View(in Django) -> APIView -> GenericAPIView -> GenericViewSet -> ModelViewSet

pagination_class is add in GenericAPIView, so you can't use it in a class inherits from APIView.You can try viewsets.GenericViewSet.

Return paged response like:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    page = self.paginate_queryset(students)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = StudentSerializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you- this helps a lot! I've inherited from GenericViewSet & updated my `list()` method, however now something odd is going on. The response looks to be paginated, but each page has the entire queryset- to follow your example, I have 21 `Students` instances in my DB and am trying `page_size` = 1. The response has 21 pages, as expected, but each page lists all 21 objects instead of just 1 per page. EDIT : this was my own fault, I forgot to pass in `page` to the serializer inside the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

You have to,

```
...
return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

manually, if you overwrite list().